# .htaccess running only script

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have site with Joomla on my local intranet. and  I'm add code on .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost:8081/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* /403-page [L,R]
```

If I'm test with type address directlink on addressbar successfully redirect, and can't open anything for directlink, and url direct to :

```
http://localhost:8081/403-page
```

the problem is, if I want open with type `http://localhost:8081/intranet` for main page of intranet I cant open this, it will test with me unscript code then put again script for open the main page, and success to open main page, then i put again script for script only use. everything is OK with I want. open anything link from website, and cant open directlink with type link on addressbar.

```
##Options -Indexes
##RewriteEngine On
##RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost:8081/.*$ [NC]
##RewriteRule ^.* /403-page [L,R]
```

how to tricks and tips for this, I can open mainpage intranet only with type on addressbar:

```
http://localhost:8081/intranet/
```

and anything type directlink set cant to open...???

Comment: how to i can open main page dirctly with type on addressbar ???? cant anyone help me please ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a condition to exclude requests for `/intranet/`:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/intranet/?$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost:8081/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* /403-page [L,R]
```